# React.js: How to create loadMore feature onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a small app with `loadMore` button.
By default, it should output 3 data, and show 3 more data each time the user clicks the load more button. 
Trying multiple ways I came up with this solution suggested by [this article](https://dev.to/debosthefirst/how-to-create-a-load-more-button-in-react-1lab#:%7E:text=create%20a%20variable%20called%20postsPerPage,posts%20before%20we%20display%20them.&text=create%20the%20handleShowMorePosts%20function%20that,load%20more%20button%20is%20clicked.).
Here is the [codesandox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hacker-news-clone-forkedoriginal-gmbt3?file=/src/App.js)

App.js

```
  let arrayForHoldingStories = [];
  const [topStoryIds] = useStories();
  const [storiesToShow, setStoriesToShow] = useState([]);
  const [next, setNext] = useState(3);

  const loopWithSlice = (start, end) => {
    const slicedStories = topStoryIds.slice(start, end);
    arrayForHoldingStories = [...arrayForHoldingStories, ...slicedStories];
    setStoriesToShow([...arrayForHoldingStories, ...slicedStories]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loopWithSlice(0, storiesPerPage);
  }, [topStoryIds]);

  const handleShowMorePosts = () => {
    let loadedMore = next + storiesPerPage;
    loopWithSlice(next, loadedMore);
    setNext(next + storiesPerPage);
  };
```

But the problem is that merging the initial array and the new array, they have same elements and it throws an error

```
Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `26991887`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
```

I tried to remove duplicates from both arrays via `forEach` or `set` functions before merging but didn't work either.
My try

```
  const loopWithSlice = (start, end) => {
    const slicedStories = topStoryIds.slice(start, end);
    arrayForHoldingStories = [...arrayForHoldingStories, ...slicedStories];

    setStoriesToShow([...arrayForHoldingStories, ...slicedStories]); //it throws mentioned error  
    /* slicedStories.forEach((uniqueId) => { //this will also throw same error
      arrayForHoldingStories.forEach((addedId) => {
        if (uniqueId !== addedId) {
          setStoriesToShow([...slicedStories, ...arrayForHoldingStories]);
        }
      });
    }); */

    /*   setStoriesToShow([   //this will also throw same error
      ...new Set([...arrayForHoldingStories, ...slicedStories])
    ]); */
  };
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your description, you don't need to have an end or start arguments to your loop with slice function. You can use the length of the `storiesToShow` state

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Stories from "./Stories";
import useStories from "./hooks/useStories";

function App() {
  const storiesPerPage = 3;
  let arrayForHoldingStories = [];
  const [topStoryIds] = useStories();
  const [storiesToShow, setStoriesToShow] = useState([]);
  const [next, setNext] = useState(3);

  const loopWithSlice = () => {
    const toShow = topStoryIds.slice(
      storiesToShow.length,
      storiesToShow.length + storiesPerPage
    );
    setStoriesToShow([...storiesToShow, ...toShow]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (topStoryIds) {
      loopWithSlice();
    }
  }, [topStoryIds]);

  const handleShowMorePosts = () => {
    let loadedMore = next + storiesPerPage;
    loopWithSlice(next, loadedMore);
    setNext(next + storiesPerPage);
  };

  console.log("next", next);
  console.log("storiesPerPage", storiesPerPage);
  console.log("loopWithSlice", loopWithSlice);
  console.log("arrayForHoldingStories", arrayForHoldingStories);
  console.log("storiesToShow", storiesToShow);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {storiesToShow.length > 0 &&
          storiesToShow.map((storyId) => (
            <Stories storyId={storyId} key={storyId} />
          ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleShowMorePosts}>load more</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can check the [sanbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hacker-news-clone-forkedoriginal-tvf9z?file=/src/App.js:0-1340) for the full code.

Comment: Hi @Josh, thank you so much. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Hi @Josh, thanks again for the answer. Could you, please, answer one more question? 
Even though your solution works fine, and this is a minor thing, but I would like to understand and solve the useEffect warning, which says: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'loopWithSlice'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)eslint" . 
If I remove the dependency array, app will crash. What would be the best solution to get rid of this warning?
Thanks in advnace

Comment: @Greg this is due to calling ``loopWithSlice`` on initial render, which creates a sort of subscription pattern for ``useEffect``. Also ``loopWithSlice`` function can change between renders, therefore this rule ensures that the function is included in the deps array in case it changes. I modified the sandbox to show a better way without calling ``loopWithSlice`` on initial render.

Comment: Hi @Josh, thanks again for your help. I got it.